# Is it possible to display a python result with react?

Tags: python, reactjs

I want to write a program using python as logic, because of the extensive libraries available in python suited for this project, and to develop the UI using react.
Is this at all possible, or is there a different method which is easier?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use react as a front end for a website, you could run python as the back end using something like flask or Django. Python can't be run in the browser, you'll need to run python on a server or run in locally on your machine if the project is just for you.